When is the first attestation for "Heracles"?
I checked PHI already, and I don't see that Hercules is ever referred to as "Heracles". You have Heraclius, Heraclea, etc., but not Heracles. Whenever the Romans referred to that hero who was the son of Zeus, they used the name Herc(u)les instead.
Heracles is a Romanization of the Greek Ἡρακλῆς, but when was the first time it was actually transliterated as such? My guess would be sometime in the 18th century or so in academic literature. Even in 1700, Danet's dictionary in English solely uses "Hercules", though there is an entry on the "Heraclidae" and "Herm-Heracles", and it mentions that the Greeks called Hercules "Heracles" (but otherwise refers to him as "Hercules").
But more specifically, what's the earliest Latin work to name him so? Is there really nothing in antiquity/late antiquity?
Keep in mind, there's a St. Heracles who is often referred to as such, but I'm specifically looking at the Greek hero.

I don't think there are any quotes that answer your question, but a corpus search for Herc- and Herac- yields some interesting examples.

@brianpck It's almost strange that they consistently call him Hercules when they are very familiar with Heraclius, Heraclids, Heracleopolis, etc. Although I guess not too weird. They also only call Athena "Minerva", even though they're fully aware of Athens and Hermathena.
